# xslt sum values in multiple documents

Tags: xml, xslt, collections

I tried using the document function to process multiple .xml-documents

```
sum(document(/folder/folders/*)//element)
```

The folders have varying names, so this path has to be dynamic(I used * in the actual .xsl), but the document function does not work with multiple folders with different names, does it ?

As this did not work, I was looking for another solution and stumbled over the collection function, which can be used with saxon.

```
<value-of select="sum((collection('/folder/folders?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')//element)"
```

(recursive="yes" is set for collection to go through the subfolders)

But this does not seem to work correctly. I could not find a good documentation of the function, either.

Is there a a good documentation of the function or could you provide me with any help ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you provide some small sample xml files that support your question?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Saxon's 9.5 `collection` function is http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/sourcedocs/collections.html and http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/fn/collection. You might want to try a complete file URL adapted to the file system you work with e.g. `collection('file:///C:/folder/folders?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')`. If you still have problems then explain exactly which directory structure you have.

The `document` function does not operate on URLs, it takes nodes thus for `sum(document(/folder/folders/*)//element)` to work you need to have an input document

```
<folder>
  <folders>
    <foo>file1.xml</foo>
    <bar>file2.xml</bar>
  </folders>
</folder>
```

where the `file1.xml` and `file2.xml` then would need to contain `element` elements with numeric values you want to sum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the document function will accept multiple URIs, and you can take advantage of this to sum across multiple documents - even in XSLT 1.0. Though in XSLT 1.0 the problem is that the multiple URIs must be present as the values of nodes in a node-set, they cannot be dynamically computed. You need to make it clearer how you are computing the URIs of the documents and whether you are able to take advantage of XSLT 2.0.